# Is it necessary to create custom shapes which connected to bones? Can I just animate with bones?

Tags: rigging

I have followed this tutorial recently:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=miphUq4uwNM&index=9&list=PLyelx0TsmSpcgsINPt6fOh3yWjTjk2Nz9

But I can't edit the orient custom shape like he did in 11:18 cause it does't appear in edit mode. It is in the wrong place though I put orient custom shape button. So I wonder if it is not necessary to create shapes for bones before animating. Can't I just grab and rotate bones when animating?

If you know the answer to my question or how to deal with couldn't see custom shape in edit mode, please let me know. Thanks a lot! :)

Sorry for asking such a simple question. I'm new to blender.

Comment: To choose a Custom Shape you have to be in Pose mode, select the bone, then go into Properties > Bone > Display. But I guess you have to give your shape a bit of thickness, otherwise it won't display anything, so create for example a circle then extrude and scale a bit. But of course you don't have to necessarily use a custom shape. Also you can choose a different appearance for your bones in Properties > Data > Display and choose B-Bone for example. In edit mode you can thin the bone with ctrl alt S

Comment: If you decide to use a custom shape, keep the shape in another layer so it doesn't bother you. Don't delete it. You can come back to this shape anytime you want to make some changes on it.

Comment: @moonboots what does "keep the shape in another layer" mean? After I set the shape to be the custom shape of the bone, the shape disappears in the outliner. Is it alright? And does it work if I just animate with bones? thanks for sharing your knowledge :) And sorry for my poor English...

Comment: The shape shouldn't disappear in the Outliner, I don't know what's happening. And yes of course you can animate without changing the bone shape.